# parsing asn.1 with bouncycastle

Tags: decode, bouncycastle, asn.1

I have some asn.1 encoded data. I have some success decoding it with bouncycastle but I hit the wall with quite complex example. It must be doable, but can't get further, hope you could help me, here is the example data:

```
A1 81 A9 02 02 1C 1F 02 01 15 30 81 9F 55 02 01 14 A0 81 98 A4 81 95 6B 10 30 0E 80 04 00 00 01 1F A1 06 30 04 80 02 33 32 63 06 30 04 80 02 33 32 61 0E 30 0C 80 0A 30 32 32 33 37 38 33 36 31 30 62 06 30 04 80 02 33 32 64 02 87 00 6B 13 30 11 80 04 00 00 01 1F A1 09 30 07 80 05 23 23 37 30 30 4E 01 02 0A 01 16 67 12 30 10 A3 0E 81 0C 2B 34 38 32 32 33 37 38 33 36 31 30 68 0F 30 0D A3 0B 82 09 32 32 38 36 35 33 33 39 38 65 09 30 07 80 05 23 23 37 30 30 7E 12 A0 10 18 0E 32 30 31 36 30 33 30 32 32 32 30 31 33 36

CSTA Browser decoded:

rOSE.roiv-apdu
{ -- SEQUENCE -- 
    invokeID = 7199,
    operation-value = 21 (cSTAEventReport),
    argument
    { -- SEQUENCE -- 
        crossRefIdentifier = '01 14'H,
        eventSpecificInfo.callControlEvents.delivered
        { -- SEQUENCE -- 
            connection.both
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                callID = '00 00 01 1F'H,
                deviceID.staticID
                { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                    deviceIdentifier.dialingNumber = "32" '33 32'H
                }
            },
            alertingDevice.deviceIdentifier
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                deviceIdentifier.dialingNumber = "32" '33 32'H
            },
            callingDevice.deviceIdentifier
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                deviceIdentifier.dialingNumber = "0223783610" '30 32 32 33 37 38 33 36 31 30'H
            },
            calledDevice.deviceIdentifier
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                deviceIdentifier.dialingNumber = "32" '33 32'H
            },
            lastRedirectionDevice.notKnown NULL,
            originatingNIDConnection.both
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                callID = '00 00 01 1F'H,
                deviceID.staticID
                { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                    deviceIdentifier.dialingNumber = "##700" '23 23 37 30 30'H
                }
            },
            localConnectionInfo = 2 (alerting),
            cause = 22 (newCall),
            networkCallingDevice.deviceIdentifier
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                deviceIdentifier.explicitPublic.international = "+48223783610" '2B 34 38 32 32 33 37 38 33 36 31 30'H
            },
            networkCalledDevice.deviceIdentifier
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                deviceIdentifier.explicitPublic.national = "228653398" '32 32 38 36 35 33 33 39 38'H
            },
            associatedCallingDevice.deviceIdentifier
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                deviceIdentifier.dialingNumber = "##700" '23 23 37 30 30'H
            },
            extensions
            { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                security
                { -- SEQUENCE -- 
                    timestamp = "20160302220136" '32 30 31 36 30 33 30 32 32 32 30 31 33 36'H
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

bouncycastle's dump produces something like that:

```
00 AC A1 81 A9 02 02 5F B9 02 01 15 30 81 9F 55 02 01 91 A0 81 98 A4 81 95 6B 10 30 0E 80 04 00 00 03 98 A1 06 30 04 80 02 33 32 63 06 30 04 80 02 33 32 61 0E 30 0C 80 0A 30 32 32 33 37 38 33 36 31 30 62 06 30 04 80 02 33 32 64 02 87 00 6B 13 30 11 80 04 00 00 03 98 A1 09 30 07 80 05 23 23 37 30 30 4E 01 02 0A 01 16 67 12 30 10 A3 0E 81 0C 2B 34 38 32 32 33 37 38 33 36 31 30 68 0F 30 0D A3 0B 82 09 32 32 38 36 35 33 33 39 38 65 09 30 07 80 05 23 23 37 30 30 7E 12 A0 10 18 0E 32 30 31 36 30 33 30 34 31 35 32 32 34 30 
buf:Tagged [1] IMPLICIT 
    Sequence
        Integer(24505)
        Integer(21)
        DER Sequence
            DER ApplicationSpecific[21] (0191)
            Tagged [0]
                Tagged [4] IMPLICIT 
                    Sequence
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[11]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                    DER Octet String[4] 
                                Tagged [1]
                                    DER Sequence
                                        Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                            DER Octet String[2] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[3]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                    DER Octet String[2] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[1]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                    DER Octet String[10] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[2]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                    DER Octet String[2] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[4]
                            Tagged [7] IMPLICIT 
                                DER Octet String[0] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[11]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                    DER Octet String[4] 
                                Tagged [1]
                                    DER Sequence
                                        Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                            DER Octet String[5] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[14] (02)
                        DER Enumerated(22)
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[7]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [3]
                                    Tagged [1] IMPLICIT 
                                        DER Octet String[12] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[8]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [3]
                                    Tagged [2] IMPLICIT 
                                        DER Octet String[9] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[5]
                            Sequence
                                Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
                                    DER Octet String[5] 
                        DER ApplicationSpecific[30]
                            Tagged [0]
                                GeneralizedTime(20160304152240GMT+01:00)
```

and I am trying to parse it:

```
protected void parse() {
    logger.trace("Executing parse()");

    try {

        ASN1InputStream input = new ASN1InputStream(asn1Data);
        ASN1Primitive p;

        if ((p = input.readObject()) != null) {
            ASN1TaggedObject o1 = ASN1TaggedObject.getInstance(p);
            ASN1Sequence s1 = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(o1.getObject());
            invokeID = Integer.parseInt(s1.getObjectAt(0).toString());
            operationValue = Integer.parseInt(s1.getObjectAt(1).toString());

            DERSequence ders = (DERSequence) DERSequence.getInstance(s1.getObjectAt(2));
            DERApplicationSpecific das = (DERApplicationSpecific) ders.getObjectAt(0);
            crossRefIdentifier = das.getContents();



     //here are some experiments, but can't get the right objects I could parse / walk through

            ASN1TaggedObject o2 = ASN1TaggedObject.getInstance(ders.getObjectAt(1));
            DERTaggedObject dto = (DERTaggedObject) o2.getObject();

            ASN1Sequence s2 = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(dto.getObject());
            DERApplicationSpecific das1 = (DERApplicationSpecific) s2.getObjectAt(0);
            ASN1Sequence s3 = (ASN1Sequence) das1.getObject();

            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.warn("exception while parsing ASN1 data", ex);
    }

}
```

as you can see I've been able to decode some basic tags (ie. invokeID, operation-value and crossRefIdentifier) but can't get deeper in the tree (callId, callingNumber ...).
If you have experience in that matter I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very complex ASN.1 object. There are several places where it could go wrong with another sample due to structure differences. Here is an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;

namespace Asn1ParseBouncy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bytes2Parse = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\a.req");

            // (0,169) CONTEXT SPECIFIC(1)
            DerTaggedObject rootObj = (DerTaggedObject)Asn1Object.FromByteArray(bytes2Parse);

            if (rootObj.TagNo == 1)
            {
                ParseAtRootLevel(rootObj);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Expected Tag number to be 1");
            }
        }

        private static void ParseAtRootLevel(DerTaggedObject rootObj)
        {
            // SEQUENCE under CONTEXT SPECIFIC(1)
            var seq = (Asn1Sequence)rootObj.GetObject();

            IEnumerator e = seq.GetEnumerator();
            bool hasNext;
            hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            // (3,2) INTEGER -> invokeID 
            {
                Asn1Encodable obj;

                if (!hasNext)
                {
                    throw new Exception("more entries expected in sequence");
                }
                obj = (Asn1Encodable)e.Current;

                // TODO: put in a property of class that represents whole ASN.1 message
                var invokeID = DerInteger.GetInstance(obj);

                hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            }

            // (7,1) INTEGER -> operation-value
            {
                Asn1Encodable obj;

                if (!hasNext)
                {
                    throw new Exception("more entries expected in sequence");
                }
                obj = (Asn1Encodable)e.Current;

                // TODO: put in a property of class that represents whole ASN.1 message
                var operationValue = DerInteger.GetInstance(obj);

                hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            }

            // (10,159) SEQUENCE -> argument
            {
                Asn1Encodable obj;

                if (!hasNext)
                {
                    throw new Exception("more entries expected in sequence");
                }
                obj = (Asn1Encodable)e.Current;

                var argumentSeq = Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(obj);

                // argumentData is parsed asn.1 object - argument 
                var argumentData = ParseArgumentData(argumentSeq);

                hasNext = e.MoveNext();
            }

            if (hasNext)
            {
                throw new Exception("no more entries expected in sequence");
            }
        }

        private static object ParseArgumentData(Asn1Sequence argumentSeq)
        {
            IEnumerator e = argumentSeq.GetEnumerator();
            bool hasNext;
            hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            // (13,2) APPLICATION (21) -> crossRefIdentifier  
            {
                Asn1Encodable obj;

                if (!hasNext)
                {
                    throw new Exception("more entries expected in sequence");
                }
                obj = (Asn1Encodable)e.Current;

                var crossRefIdentifierAppSpecific = (DerApplicationSpecific)obj;
                if (crossRefIdentifierAppSpecific.ApplicationTag != 21)
                    throw new Exception("Expected application tag 21");

                // TODO: put in a property of class that represents whole ASN.1 message
                var crossRefIdentifier = crossRefIdentifierAppSpecific.GetContents();

                hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            }

            // (17,152) CONTEXT SPECIFIC (0) -> eventSpecificInfo.callControlEvents.delivered  
            {
                Asn1Encodable obj;

                if (!hasNext)
                {
                    throw new Exception("more entries expected in sequence");
                }
                obj = (Asn1Encodable)e.Current;

                var eventSpecificInfo = ((DerTaggedObject)obj);

                if (eventSpecificInfo.TagNo != 0)
                    throw new Exception("Expected Context specific tag number to be 0");

                // TODO: put in a property of class that represents whole ASN.1 message
                var eventSpecificInfoData = ParseEventSpecificInfo(eventSpecificInfo);

                hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            }

            if (hasNext)
            {
                throw new Exception("no more entries expected in sequence");
            }

            // TODO: return parsed values in some class
            return null;
        }

        private static object ParseEventSpecificInfo(DerTaggedObject obj)
        {
            // still (17,152) CONTEXT SPECIFIC (0)
            var connectionBothData = ParseConnectionBoth(obj);

            return connectionBothData;
        }

        private static object ParseConnectionBoth(DerTaggedObject connectionBoth)
        {
            // (20,149) CONTEXT SPECIFIC (4)->connection.both
            var connectionBothTagged = (DerTaggedObject)connectionBoth.GetObject();

            if (connectionBothTagged.TagNo != 4)
                throw new Exception("Expected Context specific tag number to be 4");

            // Sequence under (20,149) CONTEXT SPECIFIC (4) -> connection.both
            var connectionBothSeq = (DerSequence)connectionBothTagged.GetObject();

            IEnumerator e = connectionBothSeq.GetEnumerator();
            bool hasNext;
            hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            // callID   
            {
                Asn1Encodable obj;

                if (!hasNext)
                {
                    throw new Exception("more entries expected in sequence");
                }
                obj = (Asn1Encodable)e.Current;

                // (23,16) APPLICATION (11)
                // TODO: put in a property of class that represents whole ASN.1 message
                var callIDTagged = (DerApplicationSpecific)obj;
                if (callIDTagged.ApplicationTag != 11)
                    throw new Exception("Expected tag number 11");

                // (25,14) SEQUENCE
                var callIdSeq = callIDTagged.GetObject().GetDerEncoded();

                // TODO: parse CallIdSeq -> (27,4) ContextSpecific(0), (33,6) ContextSpecific(1)

                hasNext = e.MoveNext();

            }

            // TODO: continue with (41,6) Application (3)
            // TODO: continue with (49,14) Application (1)
            // TODO: continue with (65,6) Application (2)
            // etc.

            // TOOD: return something useful
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I placed notes in the code sample according to dump from [ASN.1 Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor)
[image: dump of your sample]

You could make your life a lot easier if you had ASN.1 definition of the object. With help from [Binary Notes](http://bnotes.sourceforge.net/) you could generate classes to parse ASN.1 data object.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. BinaryNotes generated classes for me.. 
Now I am just looking for information or example of how to use them.

Comment: It is written in the documentation on [page 12](http://bnotes.sourceforge.net/BinaryNotes.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising. Unfortunately more complex methods cause exceptions (usually null pointer). Since I am trying to communicate with PBX I spoke to PBX vendor and am looking for complete asn.1 package. It looks that what I've already found cannot be used for my purposes. I am curious if BinaryNotes will handle these asn.1 files.

With asn.1 files I found simple method MonitorStart, generated very simple output: 03 03 00 33 32 , which is only small substring of the code I should have received.

Comment: I'm afraid I can not help you further with this problem. I would have to have access to all that you have (test environment, PBX ...). As for the BinaryNotes we have modified it to generate classes using bouncy castle (it looks like the example I wrote) so maybe it would be better to debug and find issues. BinaryNotes parses ASN.1 notation to xml structures and then uses xslt transformations to generate code classes.  By default it generates its own classes with annotations but maybe it would be worth to investigate and change to generate bouncy classes.

Comment: I understand and thanks for your efforts. Maybe when I receive asn1 from the vendor you could try to generate bouncycastle parsable classes for me just for one method which is EventReport. Less complex structures needed for my project I have already done by myself, and frankly speaking almost completed this one as well. At some point I had a problem reading binary octets from DERTaggedObject, but after some trial and error and casting objects in different way I finally read what I wanted. My class is not very OOP like  but should be good enough to simply read events received from PBX.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Just edit your question and put ASN.1 definition there.

Comment: @norbi771 If it's a PBX it's possible that the standards it complies with are from the ITU. If so then the schema will be buried deep somewhere within the ITU's collection of standards. Afterall, the telephony world and the ITU created ASN.1 in the first place. Maybe if the vendor were able to tell you what standards it complies with you might be able to get the schema yourself from the ITU.